# Cannot select desired programming SDK platform in Android Studio

Tags: android, sdk, android-api-levels

Well, I am trying to develop an APP for my Smartphone Samsung Galaxy Ace, which contains android 2.3.6 (Gingerbread). The problem is that I can't select a lower API to develop, as shown in the picture:
[image]

I also tried downloading the API I needed from SDK Manager
[image]

I've also seen some people changing SDK version from activity_main.xml, in the design menu, but as the picture shows, there aren't any other options available:
[image]

I tried editing build.gradle(Module:app)[image]
But it keeps giving me errors, I used tools:overrideLibrary, but it gives me more errors with more libraries to override[image]

Please, let me know if there's a way to choose API level 9 (in my case) instead of choosing a higher API

Comment: What are min sdk, target sdk and building tools versions. These 4 items are related to each others.

Comment: What do you mean by "building tools versions"? Are you talking about downloadable sdk tools? My minSdkVersion was set to 9 as iTadreik suggested. Target Sdk is set to 26 as well as compileSdkVersion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your app with the android 4.0 SDK. Once you have done that, go to your build.gradle(Module: app) and change the minSdkVersion to whatever you want. But be sure not to use api features that are not supported in android 2.3.6, refer to this image.[image: build.gradle(Module: app)] You also need to install the Sdk for android 2.3.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. That's the problem I talked about, when I try to change minSdkVersion to 9 the program asks to sync project but the build fail and it returns a message error "
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library as the library might be using APIs not available in 9
   Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 9,
    or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 14,
    or use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.graphics.drawable" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)"

Comment: From the error details I guess you have used  an external library or an Android plugin relating to drawing which requires min sdk 14

Comment: It seems SDK version 13 and lower is no longer supported by the latest Android Studio updates. This article https://9to5google.com/2016/11/21/google-play-services-gingerbread-support-end/ says that Google dropped support for API 9 and raised support up to API 14 in early 2017. So I think if you want to build an app that runs on android 2.3, you will have to use a different IDE.

Comment: Thank you iTadreik, downloading an older Android Studio IDE and installing its SDK worked like a charm, now I can make the application for my old smartphone.